# How do you manage several imported Maven BOMs

Tags: maven, gradle, dependencies, maven-bom

Using Maven BOM is a great way to manage dependencies. However, you might have situations where you have to manage imports of several BOMs within the same project.
In that situation, it's of course possible that you end up having the same dependency define in different versions.
Let's say I'm using a spring-bom and a framework for web-developement, itself importing some of the spring dependencies.
How do you guys manage such a situation? Does the concept of a "meta-BOM" exist? Where do you finally centralize your versions?

Answer (score 0):

BOMs are great, but overlapping BOMs are a problem.

AFAIK there is no general mechanism to cope with this. You can define a "super BOM" which imports BOMs and contains dependencyManagement to override versions, but it most cases, it is probably easier to track the few dependencies that overlap manually.

Comment: Yeah, that's what I'm usually doing, and find that it can be very tedious on big project. As a general rule, when it becomes too big, I try to split the project in order to keep as litte dependencies as possible ... but I'm then asking myself ... what drives the projects? what defines the architecture? Is it really the complexity of dependencies ? mmhhh